# Caching with JSP and HTML5: how to disable caching server-side

Tags: java, html, jsp, caching

I've a Jsp that returns this html 5:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Application</title>
        <!-- Some script includes here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- My html here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

At the moment the user need to disable caching into the browser, else the old page is reloaded every time.

I tried to force no-caching with a scriptlet in that way, but without success:

```
<%
response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
response.addHeader("Expires","-1");
response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
%>
```

Asde the fact the scriptlet wouldn't be a good solution, is there any way that works in JSP to disable caching?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cache-Control
```

The above header must be a cross browser one.Might that causing problems

Try

```
response.addheader('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Tomcat change context.xml

```
<Context cachingAllowed="false">
```

You can read the documentation at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html
which says for

**cachingAllowed**

*If the value of this flag is true, the cache for static resources will be used. If not specified, the default value of the flag is true.*

Comment: is there something similar in jboss?

Comment: @user1883212 I have n't really worked much on jboss but hope you find https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/jbosscache.chapt.html link useful.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using jsp files you are running this in a web container.  We do this by using a `javax.servlet.Filter` to set the header values.

I don't know of any open sources filters that already do this but it is not that difficult to write yourself.

The headers we set for HTTP/1.0:

```
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0L);
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

The headers we set for HTTP/1.1:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private,no-store,no-cache");
```